How can I add a dropdown to a search entry in GTK 4.0 with Python?
What is the best way to make a drop-down list of entries appear below a search box in GTK 4.0 with Python? I know that I can make a separate box for the results but I want them to be attached to the search box itself.
Like so:

I am making a search function for my application, and I want the results to be displayed below the search box as you type, and be selectable by pressing the arrow keys, and whatnot.
also I don't need to use any of the GTK automatic filter and sort functionality because my list is already filtered and sorted.
I feel like this is probably simple but I couldn't find any tutorials online that were of any help, even though this seems like a common pattern in UI design.
how would I achieve this?
EDIT: I feel like the most likely solution is a Gtk.Popover/Gtk.PopoverMenu attached to the SearchEntry widget, however I cannot for the life of me figure out how to attach Popovers to things in GTK 4.0.
EDIT 2: just found out about the Gtk.EntryCompletion widget, although I don't know how to use it in Python with GTK 4.0 because the set_completion method seems to be missing from the SearchEntry class. even though the apparent C function to do this is gtk_entry_set_completion.. I am really just more confused by this. Please help!
EDIT 3: Now I am considering using an Overlay to do it, but will save that for tomorrow..

I feel like I could do this if I could attach a Gtk.Popover of some sort to my search entry, I just don't know how to do that...

God the GTK documentation is awful, haha

Ok my question has been solved, It turns out the set_completion method only exists on Gtk.Entry and not Gtk.SearchEntry, instead of using SearchEntry, you can use a regular Entry and add the "looking glass" icon back yourself like so:
entry = Gtk.Entry()

# Keep this line if you wanted it to be like a SearchEntry as I did
entry.set_icon_from_icon_name(Gtk.EntryIconPosition.PRIMARY, 'edit-find')

list_store = Gtk.ListStore(str)

items = ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Date", "Fig", "Grape"]

for item in items:
    list_store.append([item])

completion = Gtk.EntryCompletion()
completion.set_model(list_store)
completion.set_text_column(0)
completion.set_inline_completion(True)

entry.set_completion(completion)

